# How to instal Zurb Foundation CLI

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to install Zurb Foundation CLI with npm.
The install seems to go well, however, when I try to run a foundation command, things get ugly.

```
foundation -v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/terminal-kit/lib/detectTerminal.js:179
exports.getParentTerminalInfo = async function getParentTerminalInfo( callback ) {
                                  ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/terminal-kit/lib/termkit.js:53:26)
```

Comment: What command did you run to install `npm install foundation -g`?

Comment: npm install -g foundation-cli

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling `npm uninstall -g foundation-cli`. Something must be bugged with the install.

Comment: Uninstalled, re-installed. Same issue. Running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please upgrade Node.js and npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade Node.js and npm.

`async` is a new ECMAScript feature which is only available in the latest Node.js versions.